# xpath multiple nodes query with custom strings

Tags: xpath

I have a working multiple node xpath query and I want to add some custom strings between the results.

```xml
<FooBar>
    <Foo>
        <Fooid>A</Fooid>
        <Booid>222</Booid>
        <Wooid>Z</Wooid>
    </Foo>
    <Foo>
        <Fooid>B</Fooid>
        <Booid>333</Booid>
        <Wooid>Y</Wooid>
    </Foo>
    <Foo>
        <Fooid>C</Fooid>
        <Booid>444</Booid>
        <Wooid>X</Wooid>
    </Foo>
</FooBar>
```

I have messed with different combinations of string-joins and/or concats, but the result was always wrong or ended up in a syntax-error. My xpath version is Xpath 2.0

`//Foo/Fooid | //Foo/Booid | Foo/Wooid`

The above xpath results in:

A

222

Z

My preferred result would be:

(A)

{222}

[Z]

what is the correct usage of string-join in order to get the brackets around the three ids?

Comment: Can you paste the portion of the xml that the expression was used on?

Comment: First of all, which version of XPath do you use? If you try to use an XPath 2 function like `string-join` with an XPath 1 implementation then you will get errors in any case that nobody can fix. I would think if you have XPath 2 support you want e.g. `//Foo/concat('(', id, ')') | //Boo/concat('{', id, '}') | Woo/concat('[', id, ']')`.but you haven't really explained which values are to be wrapped into `()` and which into `{}` or `[]`.

Comment: I have updated the post accordingly. The error is: Xpath failed due to: Required item type of first operand of '|' is node(); supplied value has item type xs:string. This means the second concat after '|' requires a different syntax?

Answer (score 1):

after doing some research and with your comments, I was able to achive the desired solution with this line:

```
//Foo/concat('(', Fooid, ')'),  //Foo/concat('{', Booid, '}'),Foo/concat('[', Wooid, ']')
```

The '|' was replaced by a comma.

Answer (score 0):

to concat these characters, use their html entity instead.

```
concat('&lpar;', //Fooid, '&rpar;')
```

for parentheses use

```
&lpar;
&rpar;
```

for brackets

```
&lbrack;
&rbrack;
```

for brackes

```
&lbrace;
&rbrace;
```

See full character entity sets [here](https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref)